# How to inherit class fields from a class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there a way to dynamically copy all of the fields in a class from script 1 to script 2 without editing script 2?

For example:

Script 1 contains:

```
class Extras
{
    public string url;
    public string itemTitle;
    public float articleDuration;
    public float yLocation;
}
```

and Script 2 contains:

```
public class Settings
{

}
```

How can I copy all fields in the `Extras` class to the `Settings` class without editing script 2?

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you have a lot of files?

Comment: Have you looked into T4 files?

Comment: Do you want to update the source-code of `Settings`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change the code on runtime, the short answer is "you can not". But, you can extend the Settings class,

```
public class AnotherSettings : Settings
{
    public string url;
    public string itemTitle;
    public float articleDuration;
    public float yLocation;
}
```

And use the the parent class with an instance of the child class,

```
Settings settings = new AnotherSettings();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields definition is telling the compiler what your class looks like, say the `Shape`. Class is not the a dynamic data structure which you can configure it anytime and anywhere. Class is the prototype with which your system can run.

So what you want? To generate a class dynamically?

It's not a reasonable idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also nest the class, but not sure of your ultimate desired need.

```
class Extras
{
    public string url;
    public string itemTitle;
    public float articleDuration;
    public float yLocation;
}
```

This one DERIVES from Extras so it gets all Extras definitions plus whatever you add.

```
public class Settings1 : Extras
{
   public string SomethingAtThisLevel;

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      if( OtherSettings.itemTitle == "TESTING" )
         SomethingAtThisLevel = "ok";
   }
}
```

OR This one just adds an instance of the given other class you want to have access to, but it is a field unto itself within the new class.

```
public class Settings2 
{
   public Extras OtherSettings;
   public string SomethingAtThisLevel;


   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      if( OtherSettings.itemTitle == "TESTING" )
         SomethingAtThisLevel = "ok";
   }
}
```